# UITableViewCell editing indentation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

After a quick search, I couldn't find answer to my problem.

The answer to this question: [How to reformat a custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405034/how-to-reformat-a-custom-uitableviewcell-during-editing-mode-to-accomodate-delet)
didn't work for me.

When my `tableView` gets into edit mode, the cell's `subViews` are indented to the right and goes off cell view. Please see attached screen shots.

I need either to reduce the indentation so that they are shifted but do not go beyond the `cell`. Or, when they enter edit mode, the cell's `subViews` are shifted a bit towards the left so that they remain within the cell.

I have designed these `UITableViewCell` in `storyboard`. I altered the indentation `Level` and `Width` in storyboard but they had no effect.

Update: Added screenshot after answer from NaCl

Normal Mode:
[image: Normal mode]

Edit Mode:
[image: Edit mode]

Change after answer from NaCl
[image: After Answer from NaCl]

Comment: Have you tried to set the "Autosizing" options for the labels and buttons to have a fixed distance from the right margin? Or do you use Autolayout?

Comment: @MartinR Yes the autoresizing is marked checked in storyboard.

Comment: @MartinR as I have mentioned a question posted earlier, did not help, had the similar suggestions. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is in your custom cell class - in `layoutSubviews` method adjust your `cell.view.frame`

```
if (self.isEditing) {

//  then shift cell frame to left side
}
else {

// then shift cell frame to right side
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but this creating a lots of problems. The method layoutSubviews is called on every change in cell. Thus if the delete button is pressed, the confirmation button appears and if I do not confirm (press the delete button with "-" sign again), the subview is shifted again to the left.. and after some repetitions it creates a mess.

Comment: Then add one flag (isHavingIndetation), use this flag in the above code if condition. Once your cell got indetation, set it enabled, so next time it won't allow to setFrame again. When your table gets normal (Done buttton event), make that flag disabled again.

Comment: Okay! I added a flag and set the frame of all subviews of cell. Now it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use this

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;  
}
```

Comment: I tried this and now the cell is not resized/indented but the subviews (UILables+UIButtons) are still indented and goes out of cell bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely stemming from your view hierarchy. The view's `contentView` automatically resizes for changes in the indentation. All your views should be subviews of `contentView` to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is a very old issue. This was fixed somehow, I don't really remember. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I noticed, thanks. I imagine others may benefit from the answer though.